# iscsiadm discovery gives multiple paths. Want to specify one

Tags: server, iscsi

I've using iSCSI to connect a server to a SAN. The SAN has multiple ethernet NICs.
When I do an iSCSI discovery...

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 172.16.0.1
```

... we get the a listed path for each available NIC:

```
$:/etc/iscsi> sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 172.16.0.1
172.16.0.1:3260,0 iqn.2000-01.com.store
169.254.219.124:3260,0 iqn.2000-01.com.store
10.0.255.82:3260,0 iqn.2000-01.com.store
172.16.0.1:3260,0 iqn.2000-01.com.name
169.254.219.124:3260,0 iqn.2000-01.com.name
10.0.255.82:3260,0 iqn.2000-01.com.name
```

What I'd like to do is set up the initiator to do 2 things automatically on bootup:

1. Connect the target from a specific interface, namely 172.16.0.1
2. Only connect a specific target, namely iqn.2000-01.com.store

I want the iSCSI initiator to start automatically, and while this is working it only connects to the 10.0.0.0 network automatically. This isn't desirable as that's where the rest of the traffic is running whereas 172.16.0.0 network is dedicated to the iSCSI link. Having said that, I can manually initiate the link to the iSCSI target using:

```
sudo iscsiadm -m node --targetname "iqn.2000-01.com.store" --portal "172.16.0.1:3260,0" --login
```

This works fine, but again, needs this to be automatic.

Please let me know if there's a way to handle this.

Thanks!!

(Please note that I've obfuscated the target name for privacy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple ways of doing this. The quick and dirty way is to delete the /etc/iscsi/nodes/iqn*/whateverIP directory for each one you don't want. 
Alternatively, you can edit the 'default' file under each iqn to change connection from automatic to manual. But, if you do another discovery, your changes will be overwritten.

There also appears to be a way to bind an physical NIC to an iface file which will allow you to control the network that the iscsi traffic flows.