# iSCSI volume not available during startup

Tags: dependencies, iscsi

I have successfully connected to my iSCSI target, mounted the volume and added the volume to fstab. After login, the volume is available and working.

My problem is, that the iSCSI is supposed to be used by Docker, and it seems like the volume is mounted AFTER Docker is started. The result is, that I am having a blank db in my container. When manually restarting the container, with reference to the iSCSI volume, the container starts with data from iSCSI volume.

Is there a way to ensure that Docker, or any other service, starts with a dependency on a iSCSI mounted volume?

Best regards,
Allan

Answer (score 0):

iSCSI was late for boot, because there where several nodes pointing to the same volume. Disabling the one that wasent working, made the iSCSI service start normally and ready to serve Docker during boot.

I was inspired by: [iscsiadm discovery gives multiple paths. Want to specify one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390344/iscsiadm-discovery-gives-multiple-paths-want-to-specify-one)